# Is this not an O(n) algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree, time-complexity

I'm trying to figure out why my algorithm is passing all the test cases that don't timeout. As far as I can tell, it is an O(n) algorithm since it is the execution of a sequence of O(n) algorithms. That makes it curious to me why it is timing out. I can't think of a way to significantly reduce the number of operations involved here (I think of slight operations by using leaner data structures, but that doesn't reduce the complexity).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

/// <summary>
/// 
/// Solution to https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-tree
/// 
/// Explanation of algorithm:
/// 
/// Given a tree like 
/// 
///       Val=100
///           \
///         Val=200
///           /   \
///          /     Val=100
///      Val=100
///     /       \
///   Val=500    Val=600
///
/// set a field for each node showing the sum of the values
/// in the subtree whose root is that node, making it into
/// 
///       Val=100
///       Sum=1600
///           \
///         Val=200
///         Sum=1500
///          /   \
///         /     Val=100
///        /      Sum=100
///      Val=100
///      Sum=1200
///     /        \
///   Val=500    Val=600
///   Sum=500    Sum=600
/// 
/// Then we can easily find minimum difference between the sum of
/// two trees that result from severing a branch: if the root node
/// is R and we sever node N, then the difference between the two
/// sums is |R.Sum - 2 * N.Sum|. 
///
/// </summary>

class Node
{
    public int Val { get; set; }
    public Node Parent { get; set; } = null;
    public List<Node> Neighbors { get; set; } = new List<Node>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Sum of values in descendant nodes
    /// </summary>   
    public int DescendantsSum { get; set; } = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sum of values in tree whose root is this node
    /// </summary>
    public int TreeSum { get { return Val + DescendantsSum; } }
}

class Solution
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Builds the parent relation between nodes
    /// Complexity: O(n) where n is the number of nodes
    /// </summary>
    static Node BuildToTree(Node[] nodes)
    {
        Node root = nodes[0]; // use arbitrary node as the root 

        var Q = new Queue<Node>();
        Q.Enqueue(root);
        while(Q.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = Q.Dequeue();
            foreach(var neighbor in current.Neighbors.Where(nbr => nbr != current.Parent && nbr.Parent == null))
            {
                neighbor.Parent = current;
                Q.Enqueue(neighbor);
            }
        }
        return root;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the sums of the descendant trees of each node
    /// Complexity: O(n) where n is the number of nodes
    /// </summary>
    static void SetSums(Node[] nodes)
    {
        foreach(var node in nodes)
            for (var parent = node.Parent; parent != null; parent = parent.Parent)
                parent.DescendantsSum += node.Val;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the minimum difference between the sum of
    /// two trees that result from severing a branch.
    /// </summary>
    static int MinDiff(Node[] nodes, Node root)
    {
        return nodes
                .Skip(1)
                .Min(node => Math.Abs(root.TreeSum - 2 * node.TreeSum));
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string curdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(
            Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(curdir, @"..\..\", "TestFiles\\SampleInput.txt"))
        );
        int N = Int32.Parse(file.ReadLine());
        int[] vals = Array.ConvertAll(file.ReadLine().Split(' '), Int32.Parse);
        Node[] nodes = vals.Select(val => new Node() { Val = val }).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0, n = N - 1; i < n; ++i)
        {
            int[] pair = Array.ConvertAll(file.ReadLine().Split(' '), Int32.Parse);
            int p = pair[0] - 1, d = pair[1] - 1; 
            nodes[p].Neighbors.Add(nodes[d]);
            nodes[d].Neighbors.Add(nodes[p]);
        }
        Node root = BuildToTree(nodes);
        SetSums(nodes);
        Console.WriteLine(MinDiff(nodes, root));
    }
}
```

Comment: O(n) algorithms can time-out, if they are slow enough.

Comment: Trees are usually log(n) during insertion right? Maybe you are overthinking it.

Comment: Strongly consider moving this to [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/), where time complexity is a primary topic.  Many computer scientists there should be able to help with this type of question.  If you do move it, make sure to delete it from here first, then post it there; cross-posting is seriously frowned upon.

Comment: An algorithm's complexity has little to do with its execution time. Whether for every member of a list an algorithm prints the member or generates the millionth digit of the Fibonacci sequence, it's still O(n).

Comment: If I'm reading it right. It looks as though you are calculating the descendants of all nodes here. That means you are calculating ancestors repeatedly for each sibling node. That's not in O(n). You'd want to use the same algorithm that you'd use to traverse a tree and find leaf nodes. Summing once as for each node that is traversed upwards. (although that's not in O(n) either, unless there is only 1 branch.)

Comment: When you have loop, count that as O(n). When you have loop inside loop, count that as O(n^2). When you have 2 loops at the same level that is O(2n) which is similar to O(n). If your loop increases by 2 (something other than 1), then it is usually O(log n). Your SetSums pretty much tells me it is O(n^2).

Comment: You can solve this problem with a single recursive traversal. The key is: `node_sum = node_value + ComputeSums(left_node) + ComputeSums(right_node);`

Answer (score 0):

Your SetSums() function is O(n^2) (consider a tree with all the nodes linked into a list).  You should walk the tree in post-order, or a reverse topological order, and calculate the sum of each parent from the sums of its children.